# Tensorflow inference for modified Inception V3 model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Went thru https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic and was able to run inference MNIST example using Tensorflow Serving server.

Now, I would like to use a trained modified InceptionV3 model (which generates 2 files: .pb and .txt) to export and use it for inference.

Serving Basic tutorial use mnist_saved_model.py for training and exporting the model. Is this file to be modified for the trained modified InceptionV3 model? Also, what is the difference between mnist_saved_model.py and mnist_export.py?

Looked at [How to serve the Tensorflow graph file (output_graph.pb) via Tensorflow serving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237940/how-to-serve-the-tensorflow-graph-file-output-graph-pb-via-tensorflow-serving) but the example mnist_saved_model.py creates a directory called 1 and subdirectories as shown below

$> ls /tmp/mnist_model/1

saved_model.pb  variables

Thoughts??