# Convert graph (pb) to SavedModel for gcloud ml-engine predict

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I trained an object detector using Cloud Machine Learning Engine according to the [recent post by Google’s Derek Chow on the Google Cloud Big Data And Machine Learning Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine) and now want to predict using Cloud Machine Learning Engine.

The instructions include code to export the Tensorflow graph as output_inference_graph.pb but not how to convert protobuf format (pb) into the SavedModel format required for gcloud ml-engine predict.

I reviewed the [answer by Google’s @rhaertel80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291797/how-to-deploy-locally-trained-tensorflow-graph-file-to-google-cloud-platform/44292448#44292448) for how to convert a “Tensorflow For Poets” image classification model and the [answer provided by Google’s @MarkMcDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o) for how to convert a “Tensorflow For Poets 2” image classification model but neither appears to work for the object detector graph (pb) described in the blog post.

How does one convert that object detector graph (pb) so it can be used or gcloud ml-engine predict, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SavedModel contains a [MetaGraphDef](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto) inside its [structure](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md).
To create a SavedModel from a GraphDef in python you may want to use builder as described in the link.

```
export_dir = ...
...
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess,
                                       [tag_constants.TRAINING],
                                       signature_def_map=foo_signatures,
                                       assets_collection=foo_assets)
...
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
  ...
  builder.add_meta_graph(["bar-tag", "baz-tag"])
...
builder.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I do not understand how to accommodate the specific signature of the model in the blog post.  [It appears to have input of image_tensor:0 and output of detection_boxes:0, detection_scores:0, detection_classes:0, and num_detections:0.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)  What exactly is the code for this signature, please?

Comment: To build a signature def, TensorFlow provides some utilities.  In the "serving_basic", it says "Further, to help build signature defs easily, the SavedModel API provides signature def utils. Specifically, in the mnist_saved_model.py code snippet above, we use signature_def_utils.build_signature_def() to build predict_signature and classification_signature."

Comment: For more specific usage, you can check a test https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/signature_def_utils_test.py#L44

Answer (score 1):

this post saved me! hope to help people who come here. I use the method exported successfulhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/48102615/6124383

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/15855/commits/81ec5d20935352d71ff56fac06c36d6ff0a7ae05

```
def export_model(sess, architecture, saved_model_dir):
  if architecture == 'inception_v3':
    input_tensor = 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0'
  elif architecture.startswith('mobilenet_'):
    input_tensor = 'input:0'
  else:
    raise ValueError('Unknown architecture', architecture)
  in_image = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_tensor)
  inputs = {'image': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(in_image)}
   out_classes = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
  outputs = {'prediction': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(out_classes)}
   signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
  )
   legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
   # Save out the SavedModel.
  builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(saved_model_dir)
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
      tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature
    },
    legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
  builder.save()

#execute this in the final of def main(_):
export_model(sess, FLAGS.architecture, FLAGS.saved_model_dir)

parser.add_argument(
      '--saved_model_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/saved_models/1/',
      help='Where to save the exported graph.'
  )
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.