# How to serve retrain model with tensorflow-serving and RESTful API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am new to Tensorflow. Just managed to build a simple image classifier with this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/

I am trying to serve the model with Docker. It seems that I need to export trained model to SavedModel

I managed to create SavedModel using answer in this question: [How to serve retrained Inception model using Tensorflow Serving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237940/how-to-serve-retrained-inception-model-using-tensorflow-serving)

The problem is I have no I idea how to call image classification with RESTful API.

Comment: I ended up with grpc client.